# Trying to deploy GWT project in Tomcat ends with offending class error

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, deployment, webserver

I'm trying to deploy my GWT project in Tomcat but i'm always getting this error:

```
Jul 16, 2013 9:16:52 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\Dennis\Documents\workspaceMA\xampp\tomcat\webapps\rfds\WEB-INF\lib\gwt-dev.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

When i'm trying to open the webpage i get following error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /rfds/
type Status report
message /rfds/
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.41
```

After searching these jar files in mit web-inf/lib directory i found a gwt-dev.jar (about 33Mb) and a gwt-servlet.jar (about 6Mb) and about 10-20 other jar files regarding other tools i used in my project (membrain, drools, jdbc driver etc.). Do I have dependency issues? Has someone an solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Thou shall never deploy `gwt-user.jar` and/or `gwt-dev.jar`!**

Deploy `gwt-servlet.jar` if you use GWT-RPC or RequestFactory. If you're not using managed dependencies (Maven, etc.) you might have to deploy `gwt-servlet-deps.jar` too, which you'll find in the GWT SDK zip bundle. Otherwise, your dependency manager (Maven, etc.) should take care of transitive dependencies fro you.

If you use managed dependencies, put `gwt-user` and `gwt-dev` in the `provided` scope (or whatever is equivalent for your build tool / dependency manager if you're not using Maven).

See http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideDeploying.html#DevGuideDeployingServletContainerUsingRPC

Comment: Okay, thanks! Seems to be working now.. i made also some other mistakes, like i just copied everything from the build /war/ folder into my tomcat/webapps/ and didn't realize that I only have to copy several files into my webapps deployment folder :/

Comment: You *are* supposed to copy your whole /war/ (or actually zip it up into a WAR file), if you think you don't, then you possibly have a configuration issue (pro tip: try passing the `-deploy` argument to the GWT Compiler to output outside your war)

Comment: It seems like the Eclipse Maven plugin doesn't honor the dependency scopes. My target/ does neither contain gwt-user-2.8.0-beta1.jar nor gwt-dev-2.8.0-beta1.jar yet I keep getting those deployed in .metadata/.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/${myapp}/WEB-INF/lib