# How much is gwt-dev needed for a compiled app?

Tags: java, gwt

I want to know how much is `gwt-dev` needed for a compiled app that is deployed into a container like Tomcat or JBoss.

There are some third-party libraries that includes this in the dependency and then eventually it will be copied into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. There's an issue with Google App Engine that these two cannot be uploaded so I just delete these.

By any chance a GWT app, will there be any dependency with gwt-dev when compiled and deployed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short**: 
no.

**Long version**:
According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810582/gwt-difference-between-gwt-user-jar-and-gwt-dev-jar) you don't need that in java -> class complilation nor with Google App Engine. The answer on that question also states GAE survives well without the dependency, even gwt-user is not needed.

**So,** based on that I would assume you will feel free to delete the whole dependency.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678410/trying-to-deploy-gwt-project-in-tomcat-ends-with-offending-class-error says: *'Thou shall never deploy gwt-user.jar and/or gwt-dev.jar!'* Guite straigh forward then, what to do ;)

Answer (score 0):

You MUST NOT deploy either `gwt-dev` or `gwt-user`. `gwt-servlet` is a subset of `gwt-user` that's meant to be deployed in your `WEB-INF/lib`.

If you do have libs that declare a dependency on `gwt-dev`, it's likely that it shouldn't be deployed either (otherwise it would declare `gwt-dev` with a `provided` scope, or as an `optional` dependency), so use them in the appropriate scope / sourceSet / whatever so they're only used at compile time and not packaged within your WAR.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/17678786/116472